# compare timestamp with "online files"

Tags: bash, comparison, timestamp, wget

I do something like

```
wget --user=userName --password=passWord  --timestamping https://url.to/a/file.csv.gz
gzip -cd file.csv.gz > file.csv
```

(not tested)

Please note that the server requires authentication.

The file will only be downloaded, if it's newer than the local file. This is good.

However, also line 2 should only be executed if the remote file is newer than the local file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just test to see if the modification time of the `file.csv.gz` is newer than the `file.csv`.

On Linux:

```
if [ $(stat -c '%Y' file.csv.gz) -gt $(stat -c '%Y' file.csv) ]; then
    gzip -cd file.csv.gz > file.csv
fi
```

On BSD (like Mac OS X):

```
if [ $(stat -f '%m' file.csv.gz) -gt $(stat -f '%m' file.csv) ]; then
    gzip -cd file.csv.gz > file.csv
fi
```

Other systems may have different arguments to `stat`; check `man stat` on your system, or `help stat` if it's a shell builtin.

Comment: just tried that... I get an error message like `stat: can't read file system information` (sorry it's not in english on my computer)

Comment: @speendo Sorry, the arguments to `stat` are different on Linux and BSD (such as Mac OS X, which I was reading docs on). I've edited my answer to include both version; check the arguments to `stat` for details. In particular, you want the format string that gives you modification date in seconds since the epoch.